# ng-select disable form control not working in reactive form angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ngselect

I was trying to setvalue to my form and would like to disable the form.

Somehow if I setvalue to form it is working fine but as soon I write disable method my ng-select value is going out.

Have anyone faced same issue while disabling the ng-select with values?

```js
form = new FormGroup({
    code: new FormControl()
});

values = [{
        value: "0"
        label: "test1"
    },
    {
        value: "1"
        label: "test2"
    }
]
//I am setting values using setvalue and disbling after wards
this.form.controls['code'].setValue('0')
this.form.disable();
```

```html
<ng-select formControlName="code" [items]="values" bindValue="value" labelForId="code"
[clearable]="false" [selectOnTab]="true" placeholder="Select one" data-e2e-id="code">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Are you sure that you change value?*

Method to set value:

**Methods using setValue()**

```
this.form.get("code").setValue('0');
this.form.controls["code"].setValue('0');
```

**Methods using patchValue()**

```
this.form.get("code").patchValue('0');
this.form.controls['code'].patchValue('0');
this.form.patchValue({"code": '0'});
```

In you case could be the problem that form updates only after applying disablibg and you doesn`t see that you update filed on a wrong way

Comment: yeah.. sorry edited my question.. I am still seeing the issue even after setting value

Comment: can you reproduce it, because I copy paste your code and it work

Answer (score 1):

You can disable/enable a form control when you initialize it by setting `disabled` to `true` as follows

```
users.push(this.fb.group({
  userType: this.fb.control({value: 'Admin', disabled: true})
}));
```

You can do so by calling the disable/enable methods for that particular form control to perform it dynamically.

```
// To enable form control
userType.enable();

// To disable form control
userType.disable();
```